# sed for replace works manually but doesn't work from Java code

Tags: java, sed, replace

I'm able to use `sed` from command line on Windows:

```
PS C:\workspace\test_seek\src\main\java\org\example> cat .\test.txt
Testtestoldstringtesttest
PS C:\workspace\test_seek\src\main\java\org\example> sed -i 's/oldstring/newstring/g' test.txt
PS C:\workspace\test_seek\src\main\java\org\example> cat .\test.txt
Testtestnewstringtesttest
PS C:\workspace\test_seek\src\main\java\org\example> sed -i 's/newstring/oldstringagain/g' test.txt
PS C:\workspace\test_seek\src\main\java\org\example> cat .\test.txt
Testtestoldstringagaintesttest
```

I'm trying to do it in Java code:

```
public class CmdTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[] cmdarr = {"cmd", "sed -i 's/oldstring/newstring/g' test.txt"};

        Process runCmd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarr);
    }
}
```

Process finish without exception but the file test.txt is not changed/updated.
I tried also:

```
    String[] cmdarr = {"cmd", "sed 's/oldstring/newstring/g' test.txt > test2.txt"};
    Process runCmd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarr);
```

and also with absoulute paths to file.

What is confusing for me - when I set path:

```
    String[] cmdarr = {"cmd", "sed -i 's/oldstring/newstring/g' notexist_badFile.txt"};
```

it doesn't throw exception.
In terminal I get `No such file or directory`.

It means that my command is not run correctly? But it is run because when I run command:

```
    String[] cmdarr = {"cmd", "/c", "sed 's/oldstring/newstring/g' test.txt > 
    test2.txt"};
```

empty file `test2.txt` was created...

Comment: That Windows command line you're showing is not `cmd` but PowerShell. Can you try replacing `{"cmd", "/c", "..."}` with `{"powershell", "-Command", "..."}`?

Comment: `String[] cmdarr = {"powershell", "-Command", "sed 's/oldstring/newstring/g' test.txt > test2.txt"};` - the same issue, it runs and nothing new or changed.